# OnKeyPress does not Fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a keyword search textbox and I want to runSearch function when user presses Enter key. But right now the event does not get fired. My code is below:

```
 onkeyPress=(e)=>{
  if(e.key === "Enter" ||e.charCode === 13||e.keyCode === 13){
 console.log('keyword value', this.state.keyword);
 this.runSearch();

 }
}
...
<input  id="search-box" placeholder="Enter a search term..." type="textbox" value={this.state.keyword} onChange={this.onKeywordInputChange} onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}   />
```

---------working code below----
https://reactarmory.com/guides/react-events-cheatsheet

```
handler=(event)=> {
  console.log("key:", event.key);
    if (event.key==="Enter"){...}
}



<input 
      id="search-box" type="textbox"
      value={this.state.keyword} 
      onChange={this.onKeywordInputChange}
    placeholder='Enter a search term...'

    onKeyPress={this.handler}
   />
```

Comment: couple things... `onkeyPress` function your `k` is not capitalized. Also, did you forget arrow notation? `onKeyPress = (e) => { }`

Comment: your method onkeyPress is not binded to the component maybe, if you declare method like above it must work

Comment: I changed to arrow function onkeyPress=e=>{...} and called the function and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `onKeyPress` is either inside a class component constructor:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);
}
```

or you use

```js
onKeyPress = (e) => {}
```

or you use a functional component and omit `this` altogether

https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-wood-khmg0

```js
function App() {
  const onKeyPress = e => console.log(e.nativeEvent);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" placeholder="type something" onKeyPress={onKeyPress} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I changed onkeyPress function to arrow function and it looks like this function didn't get executed.

Comment: It definitely works. See updated answer with link https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-wood-khmg0

Answer (score 0):

I have updated a copy of working code. I don't know why the old code does not work.

```
handler=(event)=> {
console.log("key:", event.key);
if (event.key==="Enter"){...}
}



<input 
  id="search-box" type="textbox"
  value={this.state.keyword} 
  onChange={this.onKeywordInputChange}
placeholder='Enter a search term...'

onKeyPress={this.handler}
/>
```